# Is there a way to redirect to a new page is System.NullReferenceException is triggered?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have my code configured in a way that it pulls the userid from asp.net identity and then checks to see if it's associated with a candidate id to load the view candidate page for that user.

Naturally, if that candidate id is null, it throws the exception.

Is there a way for me to tell the controller that if that exception is thrown redirect to new action?

I've tried if statements like If (candidate.CandidateId < 1 || candidate.CandidateId.ToString() == null), but either way that exception pops because candidate Id is null.

Comment: you can use the try / catch statement blocks to catch the exception and redirect

Comment: I'd use something along the lines of the process outlined here https://chrissainty.com/global-error-handling-aspnet-core-mvc/ but @David is correct - don't use exceptions for flow control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're drastically overthinking it.  There's really no reason to involve exception handling here, and one shouldn't rely on exception handling for application logic.

If the problem is that `candidate` is `null`, then check if `candidate` is `null`:

```
if (candidate == null)
{
    // perform redirect and return
}
// the rest of your logic relying on candidate
```

---

In the question you state that what's actually `null` is `CandidateId`.  This sounds far less likely to me, but I suppose it may be possible in your setup.  If that's the case, the structure is still the same:

```
if (candidate.CandidateId == null)
{
    // perform redirect and return
}
// the rest of your logic relying on candidate.CandidateId
```

Or if `CandidateId` is a `Nullable<T>`:

```
if (!candidate.CandidateId.HasValue)
{
    // perform redirect and return
}
// the rest of your logic relying on candidate.CandidateId
```

Comment: Kinda sounds like `candidate` itself is null, sprinkle some `.?` in there and it should behave as expected. Edit - Oh right the first code block. Somehow missed that.

Comment: @asawyer: I agree that `candidate` is probably the culprit here.  The use of `.?` may be appropriate, depending on the overall logic.  It sounds to me like the OP simply wants to perform a redirect if the identity returns a null user, and I suspect the simplest way to do that is just to check if the returned result is itself `null`.

Comment: Right - I somehow overlooked your first code block example. Cheers.